# zsh permission denied on Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I can't install npm on mac terminal.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmbkT.jpg)
How to fix it? I tried many times.

it says zsh : permission denied.

Comment: You have that directory first. Start your command and with npm

Answer (score 0):

You are merging two different commands in one. First, go into the directory with:

```bash
cd /Users/danielleclary/Downloads/react-gallery
```

and then run:

```bash
npm install -g serve
```